# Check port reachable in C

Tags: c, networking, tcp, ip-address, hostname

I have a C function to check a host and its port, when I use FQDN host name, the function return error like: connect() failed: connect time out, but if I use IP address instead, it seems ok, how to fix this?

Thanks.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>

int is_network_up(char *chkhost, unsigned short chkport) {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in chksock;
    struct hostent *host = NULL;

    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "socket() creation error: %s", strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }

    memset(&chksock, 0, sizeof(chksock));
    chksock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    chksock.sin_port = htons(chkport);

    /* get the server address */
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, chkhost, &(chksock.sin_addr.s_addr)) <= 0) {
        if ((host = gethostbyname(chkhost)) == NULL) {
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "%s", hstrerror(h_errno));
            return 0;
        }

        memcpy(&(chksock.sin_addr.s_addr), &(host->h_addr_list[0]),
               sizeof(struct in_addr));
    }

    /* try to connect */
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &chksock, sizeof(chksock)) < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "connect() failed: %s", strerror(errno));
        return 0;
    }

    close(sock);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: If you can't finally figure out what to do (as the BSD socket API is really a mess), you can always use my helper functions I've created before: https://github.com/H2CO3/TCPHelper/blob/master/tcpconnect.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inet_pton()` is the wrong task for that. It only accepts numerical addresses.

In former times, people used to use `gethostbyname()` for name resolution.

But as we have 2012 meanwhile, this method is outdated for several years now, as it is still restricted to `AF_INET`.

With the program below, you should achieve about the same and stay future compatible.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int is_network_up(char *chkhost, unsigned short chkport) {
    int sock = -1;
    struct addrinfo * res, *rp;
    int ret = 0;
    char sport[10];
    snprintf(sport, sizeof sport, "%d", chkport);

    struct addrinfo hints = { .ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM };

    if (getaddrinfo(chkhost, sport, &hints, &res)) {
        perror("gai");
        return 0;
    }

    for (rp = res; rp && !ret; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        sock = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,
                rp->ai_protocol);
        if (sock == -1) continue;
        if (connect(sock, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1) {
            char node[200], service[100];
            getnameinfo(res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen, node, sizeof node, service, sizeof
service, NI_NUMERICHOST);

            printf("Success on %s, %s\n", node, service);
            ret = 1;                  /* Success */
        }
        close(sock);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res);

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        printf("%s: %d\n", argv[1], is_network_up(argv[1], 22));
    }
}
```

Comment: It works very well, thanks. A little problem: compile warning like, "net.c:38: warning: implicit declaration of function 'close'", why?

Comment: @timy Did you `#include <unistd.h>`? If no, please do it. On my system here it seems to be included automatically by one of the others, but this seems to vary.

Comment: Phew, you scared me first by mentioning `gethostbyname`. I've seen that recommended often even in the last few months... +1 for saying it's outdated.

Comment: @glglgl hi, it seems memory leaking in my program, maybe the getaddrinfo cuase it?

Comment: @timy Not if you use `freeaddrinfo()` properly. Remember to use it on the original pointer, not on the one used for iteration (i.e., `res` here, not `rp`).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure name resolution is working.  See if you can ping the machine by name from the exact same environment in which your code runs.

If ping works, try `telnet <machinename> <portnumber>`  -- If both of those work it is likely a problem with your code (which I did not look at in depth, too sleepy:).

Make sure you're converting anything returned by the OS as an ip address from network order to host order.  IIRC, gethostbyname returns binary ip addresses in network order.

`ntohl` can be used on `chksock.sin_addr.s_addr` after the `memcpy` to achieve this.